# Fallo en Script: "unexpected operator"

Tags: bash, shell-script

Estoy desarrollando un script en el que me muestra información sobre un proceso introduciendo por teclado su identificador.

Quiero hacer que cuando el proceso no exista no muestre nada por pantalla.

A la hora de verificar la sentencia de si ha encontrado algún identificador salta el error.

> unexpected operator

El código es el siguiente:

```
encontrado= ps -l $identificador | cut -f 4 | grep -c $identificador
if [ $encontrado -gt 0 ]
then
    ps -l $identificador
else 
    echo no encontrado
fi
```

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Para guardar el resultado de un comando en una variable debes decir `var=$(comando)`. Por tanto, `encontrado=$(ps -l $identificador | cut -f 4 | grep -c $identificador)`.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar el resultado de un comando en una variable debes decir:

```
var=$(comando)
```

Por tanto, en tu caso debes decir:

```
encontrado=$(ps -l $identificador | cut -f 4 | grep -c $identificador)
```

Si no, el comando `encontrado= ps -l $identificador | cut -f 4 | grep -c $identificador` lo que está haciendo es ejecutar el comando `encontrado=` con una serie de parámetros `ps`, `-l $identificador`, etc.